# Error in IE when loading jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have two web pages (let's call them site A and B) that are both using the same externally sourced jQuery.  Site B is simply a subdomain of site A.  In site A, I declare the javascript as:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Site A has no problems whatsoever.

On site B, I am declaring the jQuery library slightly different but the libary is found and loaded:

```
`if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
            document.write(unescape("%3Cscript    src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));`
```

**The Problem**: In IE 8 and 9, when site B is loading, the Microsoft security error "This page is accessing information that is not under its control.  This poses a security risk.  Do you want to continue?"

**Debugging**: After viewing both site A and B in the IE JavaScript debugger, it's clear that A has no problems where as B prompts the user with this alert when the jQuery library has loaded.

Why would loading this library force the prompt on one site, but not the other?

Comment: Change https to http in site B

Comment: Make sure that in the site b you are loading jQuery before any other script that is using it.

Comment: Your `if` statement is missing a closing `}`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your site B to use http url to google:

Change this:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
```

to

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
```

You get that message in IE because of that https creates secure connection and your site is not using https (i assume).

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the DOM instead of using `document.write`. That will most likely prevent errors like this. Just do it this way:

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js';
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.head.appendChild(s);
}
```

EDIT: Hardy's answer is probably the right solution to this problem, but the point remains that this is almost always a better way to add elements to your page.